# copying items from one single linked list to another

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I've just started learning about linked lists and need help with this piece of code. I need to write a method that copies all the items from one single linked list to another.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
public static ListNode copy(ListNode list){
    //code
}
```

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, what is `ListNode`?

Comment: You obviously didn't google it, as Arrays.copyAll would've match your search quite easily.

Comment: If you know how to add items to a linked list, and how to iterate through all the items of a linked list, then you know how to copy a linked list. So which of these tasks do you need help with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just from the top of my head something to start with, but as mentioned above in the comments you should probably ask more specific questions.

```
class ListNode {
    int value;
    ListNode next;
    public ListNode(int value) {
        super();
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static ListNode copy(ListNode list){
        if (list == null)
            return null;

        ListNode res = new ListNode(list.value);
        ListNode resTmp = res;
        ListNode listTmp = list;

        while (listTmp.next != null){
            listTmp = listTmp.next;
            resTmp.next = new ListNode(listTmp.value);
            resTmp = resTmp.next;
        }

        return res;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListNode input = new ListNode(11);
        input.next = new ListNode(12);
        input.next.next = new ListNode(13);

        ListNode output = copy(input);

        while (output != null){
            System.out.println(output.value);
            output = output.next;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, sorry about the poor question this was my first crack at posting, will be sure to add more info and include my own attempts as well in future